# Does vitamin D synthesis occur in indirect sunlight?

Tags: sun-exposure, vitamin-d, sunlight

I know you don't get a tan through a glass window. But I don't know whether tanning and vitamin D are produced using identical wavelengths.
So my questions are :

-Do you synthesise vitamin D through a window

-Does indirect sunlight reflected from the walls and furniture of a sun lit room trigger vitamin D production ?

Comment: Hmm, no one answered your 2nd question regarding indirect sunlight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sunlight through the window does not stimulate vitamin D synthesis in the skin.

[Sunlight and Vitamin D (PubMed)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3897598/):

> Since glass absorbs all UVB radiation, exposure of the skin to
>   sunlight that passes through glass, plexiglass, and plastic will not
>   result in any production of vitamin D3 in the skin.

The sunlight reflected from the surfaces, especially snow, can contribute to vitamin D synthesis in the skin.

[Vitamin D status and sun exposure in India (PubMed)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3897581/):

> The geophysical parameters like...surface albedo (the fraction of
>   light reflected from earth’s surface)...affect vitamin D3 production
>   in the human body.

[Who, what, where and when—influences on cutaneous vitamin D synthesis (Progress in Biophysics and Molecular Biology)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a09a/e99dcfa345e232ab2adb27d5961081832edc.pdf)

> This process becomes significant if surface albedo is high, e.g. if
>   covered with fresh snow (albedo ~90%)...With the exception of snow,
>   most natural surfaces have a low albedo in the UV, of the order 5% for
>   vegetation, 10% for soils and rocks, and up to 20% for dry sand, the
>   same as some concretes and cement...

and ([Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285056396_Vitamin_D_The_truth_about_Vitamin_D_and_sun_exposure_demystified_Finding_the_balance_for_personal_health))

> 3-5% for water

Answer (score 1):

To produce Vitamin D you need to get radiated by light with wavelengths below 300 nm.
So let's look at the reflectance and transmittance of the materials.

A window made of glass has a transmittance of nearly 0 % for UV-Radiation.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74638/transmittance-of-glass

The reflection depends on the surrounding. Asphalt for example has a reflectance below 5 % whereas the value for snow is close to 100 %.

In general I would assume that reflected light on the northern hemisphere under daily circumstances is not enough for sufficient production of Vitamin D. If you live on a high mountain this might vary.

Comment: This answer would be improved by editing your final paragraph to be more factual and less assumption.

Comment: Your answer could also be improved by providing a reference to the wavelength of light that stimulates vitamin D production.